# MPI_Irecv does not receive any messages

Tags: c++, mpi

I try to implement a single source shortest path algorithm on a fully distributed scenario. I try to use Irecv and Send to send and receive messages. However, it seems like Irecv has never get the messages after MPI_Send is called.

My code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int rc = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int source = 0;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
int inneighbors = 0; // total remote inneighbors for local vertices
std::vector<int> sources;

read_file(argv[1]);

distance = new int [vertex_num]; // the shortest from src to every dst
parent = new int [vertex_num];
visit = new bool [vertex_num];
group = new int [vertex_num];
for (int i = 0; i < vertex_num; i++) {
    distance[i] = MAX;
    parent[i] = -1;
    visit[i] = false;
    for (int j = 0;j < size; j++) {
        int s = vertex_num * j / size;
        int e = vertex_num * (j + 1) / size;
        if (i >=s && i < e)
            group[i] = j;
    }
}

for (int i = local_vertex_num_start; i < local_vertex_num_end; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < vertex_num; j++) {
        if (local_adj_matrix[j][i] != INF && group[j] != rank){
            sources.push_back(group[j]);
            inneighbors++;
        }
    }

int color = white;
int ring_prev = rank == 0 ? size - 1 : rank - 1;
std::vector<Message> distrecv(inneighbors); // distance recv
std::vector<MPI_Request> recvreqs(inneighbors + 2); // recv requests
int prevcolor;

auto recvindex = [&](int index) {
    MPI_Irecv(distrecv.data() + index, 1, MPI_MSG, sources[index], DISTANCE_TAG,
              MPI_COMM_WORLD, recvreqs.data() + index);
    printf("proc %d recv new distance %d from proc %d\n",rank, index, sources[index]);
};

auto recvcolor = [&]() {
    MPI_Irecv(&prevcolor, 1, MPI_INT, ring_prev, TOKEN_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
              recvreqs.data() + inneighbors);
};

MPI_Irecv(0, 0, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, TERMINATION_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
          recvreqs.data() + inneighbors + 1);

for (int i = 0; i < inneighbors; ++i) {
    if (sources[i] != rank){
        recvindex(i);
    }
}

recvcolor();

distance[source] = 0;
parent[source] = source;
if (rank == 0) {
    for (int b = 0; b < vertex_num; ++b) {
        if (local_adj_matrix[a][b] != INF) {
            Message msg;
            int new_distance = distance[a] + local_adj_matrix[a][b];
                msg.distance = new_distance;
                msg.dst = b;
                msg.src = a;
                MPI_Send(&msg, 1, MPI_MSG, group[b], DISTANCE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                printf("Proc %d Send distance to %d\n",rank, group[b]);
            }
        }

    MPI_Send(&color, 1, MPI_INT, 1, TOKEN_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("proc %d Send color msg\n", rank);
}

std::vector<int> indices(inneighbors + 2);
int completed_count = 0;

MPI_Waitsome(inneighbors + 2, recvreqs.data(), &completed_count, indices.data(),
                 MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
// do something
```

Here is a test result for my code:

```
proc 1 recv new distance 0 from proc 0
proc 1 recv new distance 1 from proc 0
proc 1 recv new distance 2 from proc 0
proc 1 recv new distance 3 from proc 0
proc 1 recv new distance 4 from proc 0
proc 1 recv color
proc 0 recv new distance 0 from proc 1
proc 0 recv new distance 1 from proc 1
proc 0 recv new distance 2 from proc 1
proc 0 recv new distance 3 from proc 1
proc 0 recv color
Proc 0 Send distance to 1
Proc 0 Send distance to 1
Proc 0 Send distance to 1
Proc 0 Send distance to 1
Proc 0 Send distance to 1
```

Since MPI_Send returns, I believe the communications between Proc 0 and 1 should be completed. However, MPI_Waitsome hangs which indicates that there is no messages received, and I really don't understand the reason.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

In general, my code hangs because Proc 0 will not receive any message which thus lead to Proc 0 and Proc 1 hang. I used to think that MPI_Waitsome() will be pass on Proc 1 so that Proc 1 can start sending messages to Proc 0. However, MPI_Waitsome() will block all processes if there is any receiving operation which is not yet be done in any process.

Comment: `MPI_Send()` returns when the send buffer can be reused. That can happen even if the message  has not yet left the sender. Use `MPI_Ssend()` if you want to return after the message has started being received by the peer task.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Gilles! I have modify my code using `MPI_Ssend` instead of `MPI_Send`, but the test result is still unchanged and the out_count provided by `MPI_Waitsome` is still zero. Also, I take a look on the values in `distrecv`, which is my receive buffer, and all values in it is the default value. Now, I guess there may be something wrong about my receive process.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if I read your code correctly, only rank 0 sends data, and then `MPI_Waitsome()`. but no one is sending to `0`, and hence the hang. makes sense ?

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks for the help.